# return protocol with associated type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

how to return protocol with associated type?

```
protocol AProtocol {

}

class A: AProtocol {

}

class Main {
    func sendA() -> AProtocol {
        return A()
    }
}
```

it works.

but

```
protocol BProtocol {
    associatedtype B
}

class B: BProtocol {
    typealias B = Int
}

class Main {
    func sendA() -> AProtocol {
        return A()
    }

    func sendB() -> BProtocol { // error
        return B()
    }

// function1
    func sendB_<T: BProtocol>() -> T{
        return B() as! T
    }
}
```

i want to return 'return B()' in function 1
is it possible?

Comment: Change it to return `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function

```
func sendB_<T: BProtocol>() -> T{
    return B() as! T
}
```

you cannot return a `B` as a `T` because the person who uses the function defines what `T` is, not you and `T` can be any type that conforms to `Protocol` For example, I could do this:

```
class C: BProtocol 
{
    typealias B = Float
}

let c: C = Main().sendB_()
```

By doing that, I am setting `T` to be a `C` and the forced typecast in `sendB_()` will fail.

Unfortunately, protocols with associated types cannot, themselves, be treated like a concrete type, so the approach you took with `AProtocol` will not work.

As I see it, you have two options. Change your function return type to `B`. After all, you always do return a `B`

```
func sendB_() -> B {
    return B()
}
```

If you want to keep it generic, try

```
protocol BProtocol 
{
    associatedtype B

    init() // Needed to be able to do T() in generic function
}

func sendB_<T: BProtocol>() -> T{
    return T()
}
```

You need to add the initialiser to the protocol to make sure that an instance of type `T` always exists.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to return `BProtocol` in case 1. The thing is PAT (Protocol with Associated Types) are *not exactly* types. They act as sort of placeholder for types. So you cannot return `BProtocol` directly.

**Swift 5.1**

I am not 100% sure but I think in the next iteration of swift (5.1), they have introduced **opaque types** which allow the functionality you desire.

In that case you would be able to call it like this:

```
func sendB() -> some BProtocol { 
    return B()
}
```